Integral's computation does not match WolframAlpha result
So I'm computing the following integral:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)\ln(x)}{x}dx
\end{align}
I started out with a simple integration by parts which yielded:
\begin{align}
-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x)}{x^2 + 1}dx
\end{align}
A nifty substitution $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ and adding the new integral to the original gives:
\begin{align}
-\frac 12 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2(x)}{x^2 + 1}dx
\end{align}
The integral now warrants a fairly obvious substitution $x \to \tan x$:
\begin{align}
-\frac 12 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln^2(\tan x) dx
\end{align}
Which may be written as:
\begin{align}
-\frac 12 \frac{d^2}{ds^2} \left ( \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan^s (x)dx \right )_{s = 0}
\end{align}
Using the beta function yields:
\begin{align}
-\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{d^2}{ds^2} \left [ \sec \left ( \frac{\pi s}{2} \right ) \right ]_{s=0} = -\frac{\pi^3}{16}
\end{align}
However, Wolfram Alpha notes the answer to be $-\frac{\pi^3}{32}$, if the descrepancy has been noticed, I'd be grateful!

For $0\le s<1$, could you explain a bit as to how we have $$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2(\tan{x})dx = \left. \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\left( \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\tan{x})^sdx \right)\right|_{s=0}$$
There is nothing wrong here, I am just curious. @NEON

@Sam
I'm sorry if it comes off as a move that lacks rigour, but I utilized the Liebnitz rule for integration:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x, t) dt = b'(x)f(x, b(x)) - a'(x)f(x, a(x)) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, t) dt
\end{align}
Since the bounds are constants, you're only left with the partial derivative of the integrand.

Mistake on $\int \frac{\ln x}{x} d x=\int \ln x d(\ln x)=\frac{\ln ^2 x}{2}+c$

Your integration by parts already yields an integral with value $\pi^3/16$, so we know that this step contains an error.
Indeed, the integration by parts should be
$$u = \arctan x, \quad du = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \, dx, \\
dv = \frac{\log x}{x} \, dx, \quad v = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} \log^2 x.$$
You are simply missing the factor of $1/2$.

Oh god, couldn't have been any stupider, thanks for this!

@NEON I myself have made this type of mistake many times, so I wouldn't feel too bad about it.  In addition, the technique you used in the very next step introduced another factor of $1/2$, so it is entirely understandable that such an error would be difficult to spot.

It's good to emphaize the bug-finding strategy hinted at in this answer: numerically evaluate each expression along the way and see where the numbers don't match up—that narrows down the search for mistakes considerably!
